# mysql access denied while running

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-14.04

```
mohammadhb@mohammadhb-P43-ES3G:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for mohammadhb: 
root@mohammadhb-P43-ES3G:~# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
root@mohammadhb-P43-ES3G:~# clear
root@mohammadhb-P43-ES3G:~# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: is there no Password for user root ? if you have one try # mysql -uroot -p

Comment: Welcome here! Please ask a question. A console log is not a question.

Comment: i did try mysql -u root -p and entering my root password then but nothing happent at all . all same err again

Comment: `localhost` probably contacts the unix socket, while `127.0.0.1` tries to connect via tcp - try both.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset